# assert using unittest outside testcase class

Tags: unit-testing, assert

This works:

```
class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
      def test_choice(self):
      self.assertEquals(1, 1, 'they are equal!')

class OtherClass ( val ):
```

But I want the assertEquals in the OtherClass class and call it from the TestSequenceFunctions class. But it generates a error: "global name "self" is not defined". Please help ;)

Comment: What is the code of "OtherClass" does it inherit some other test class?